# Twilio call usage paging

Tags: c#, .net, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to get a paged list of call records from Twilio

```
var records = Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.CallResource.Read(pageSize: 10).ToList();
```

But nowhere is there anywhere to specify what the page number to retrieve is? How would I do this?

Comment: Brrr, I feel like a shower after reading those api docs.  You've got 14 arguments to filter by, starting page is not one of them.  This was optimized to make the dbase query fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sales Engineer at Twilio here.

There isn't a way to go to a specific page. You can navigate through the pages using the `previous_page_uri` and `next_page_uri` fields. I think the philosophy is that pages are a very implicit/arbitrary way of navigating your data. It's better to be explicit about what you're actually looking for, e.g., "Records from this date to this date" by using query parameters like this:

`Category=calls&StartDate=2017-10-13&EndDate=2017-10-13"`

Comment: Is there an example to do that via the .NET SDK?

Comment: @AmirHajiha I think that this is the code sample you're looking for: https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api/usage-record?code-sample=code-daily-usage-for-inbound-calls-over-a-one-month-period&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=5.x#linkcode